# Better way of concatenating multiple for loops in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe with quite a few columns and I am running multiple for loops to create variable to be used in my desired function. Is there a better(concatenated format) way/format to run these loops?

```
for x in df['A']:
    L = x

for y in df['B']:
    M = y

for w in df['C']:
    N = w

for v in df['D']:
    O = v
```

maybe also improve execution speed at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create numpy array by seelcting columns by list and [`DataFrame.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html):

```
for L,M,N,O in df[['A','B','C','D']].to_numpy():
    print (L, M, N, O)
```

Or use [`DataFrame.itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html):

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    (L, M, N, O) = (row.A,row.B,row.C,row.D)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but how would i pass value to variables L,M,N and O? I need to do this, because L,M,N and O are being called multiple times by various functions